# Can't get {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node }) to render multiple images with Gatsby + GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

Description

I am trying to use `{data.allFile.edges.map(({ node })` to render multiple (local) images to a page, but I can't run `gatsby develop` successfully.

#### Steps to reproduce

My code is as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import WideGalleryLayout from "../components/wide-gallery-layout"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { css } from "@emotion/core"

export default () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query imageQuery {
      allFile(
        filter: {
          extension: { regex: "/(jpg)/" }
          relativeDirectory: { eq: "images/japan" }
        }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            base
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                aspectRatio
                base64
                src
                srcSet
                sizes
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <WideGalleryLayout>
      {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node })
      => (
        <Img fluid=
        {node.childImageSharp.fluid}
        />
      ))}
    </WideGalleryLayout>
  )
}
```

When I run `gatsby develop` I get the below error message:

```
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.036s
success load plugins - 1.219s
success onPreInit - 0.003s
success initialize cache - 0.005s
success copy gatsby files - 0.055s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.015s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.008s
success source and transform nodes - 0.369s
success building schema - 0.241s
success createPages - 0.037s
success createPagesStatefully - 0.075s
success updating schema - 0.022s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.002s

 ERROR #85911  GRAPHQL

There was a problem parsing "/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/components/japan-component.js"; any GraphQL
fragments or queries in this file were not processed.

This may indicate a syntax error in the code, or it may be a file type
that Gatsby does not know how to parse.

File: src/components/japan-component.js


 ERROR #85911  GRAPHQL

There was a problem parsing "/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-1.js"; any GraphQL
fragments or queries in this file were not processed.

This may indicate a syntax error in the code, or it may be a file type
that Gatsby does not know how to parse.

File: src/pages/folio-1.js

failed extract queries from components - 0.314s
success write out redirect data - 0.010s
success onPostBootstrap - 0.002s
info bootstrap finished - 5.465s
success run page queries - 0.021s - 4/4 189.04/s
success write out requires - 0.004s
warn ESLintError:
/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/components/layout.js
  3:26  warning  'Link' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  8:9   warning  'data' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)

warn ESLintError:
/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-2.js
  3:10  warning  'Image' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

warn ESLintError:
/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-3.js
  3:10  warning  'Image' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed


/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-1.js
  39:7  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  37 |     <WideGalleryLayout>
  38 |       {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node })
> 39 |       => (
     |       ^
  40 |         <Img fluid=
  41 |         {node.childImageSharp.fluid}
  42 |         />

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


File: src/pages/folio-1.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-1.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (39:6)

  37 |     <WideGalleryLayout>
  38 |       {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node })
> 39 |       => (
     |       ^
  40 |         <Img fluid=
  41 |         {node.childImageSharp.fluid}
  42 |         />

File: src/pages/folio-1.js:39:6

failed Building development bundle - 3.355s
warn ESLintError:
/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/components/layout.js
  3:26  warning  'Link' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
  8:9   warning  'data' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)

warn ESLintError:
/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-2.js
  3:10  warning  'Image' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

warn ESLintError:
/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-3.js
  3:10  warning  'Image' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed


/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-1.js
  39:7  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  37 |     <WideGalleryLayout>
  38 |       {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node })
> 39 |       => (
     |       ^
  40 |         <Img fluid=
  41 |         {node.childImageSharp.fluid}
  42 |         />

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


File: src/pages/folio-1.js


 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

/Users/oliverholms/Dropbox/omh-blog/src/pages/folio-1.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (39:6)

  37 |     <WideGalleryLayout>
  38 |       {data.allFile.edges.map(({ node })
> 39 |       => (
     |       ^
  40 |         <Img fluid=
  41 |         {node.childImageSharp.fluid}
  42 |         />

File: src/pages/folio-1.js:39:6

failed Re-building development bundle - 0.083s
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
```

I was following the steps in this eggheads video [Add multiple images from a directory with gatsby-image](https://egghead.io/lessons/gatsby-add-multiple-images-from-a-directory-with-gatsby-image?pl=using-gatsby-image-with-gatsby-ea85129e). I am 99% sure that I copied his code correctly — with the correct directory for my files, but the CLI can't `develop` successfully.

#### Expected result

I should be able to render multiple images from a directory with `gatsby-image`. I have checked at http://localhost:8000/___graphql and my graphQL query returns my images with the other data I requested.

#### Actual result

I can't `gatsby develop` successfully or render my images. The terminal error message points to the arrow function as the problem element ('expected comma' etc.)

I am new to this so please factor that into the technical language in your answers.

#### Environment

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.5
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.18.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.14.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 84.0.4147.125
    Safari: 13.1.1
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.23.12 => 2.23.12
    gatsby-image: ^2.4.16 => 2.4.16
    gatsby-plugin-emotion: ^4.3.10 => 4.3.10
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.6.27 => 2.6.27
    gatsby-plugin-typography: ^2.5.10 => 2.5.10
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.3.23 => 2.3.23
    gatsby-transformer-json: ^2.4.11 => 2.4.11
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^2.8.27 => 2.8.27
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.5.13 => 2.5.13
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.12.87
```

Comment: try just  ` => <Img` .. use `key`

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Sena's comment, you can shorten the code to

```
{data?.launches?.launches?.map((launch: any) => (
   <LaunchTile key={launch.id} launch={launch} />
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try coding like this below

```
{data.launches &&
    data.launches.launches &&
    data.launches.launches.map((launch: any) => (
      <LaunchTile key={launch.id} launch={launch} />
    ))}
```

reference url : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/queries/